# Alert box not getting displayed in react-native app

Tags: react-native, alert

I am trying to display two AutoComplete fields and a button, and when the button is clicked, it checks whether any of the text fields is empty or not. If any of them is empty I display an alert using an "Alert" component of react-native.
It is a class based component.

Code:

```
    import { Alert } from 'react-native';
    
    ............
    ............
    
    onSubmit = () => {
            var firstItem = this.state.firstItem;
            var secondItem = this.state.secondItem;
                if(firstItem.trim() == "" || secondItem.trim() == "")
                {
                    console.log("AlertBox: ");
                    Alert.alert(
                        "Alert Title",
                        "My Alert Msg",
                        [
                          {
                            text: "Cancel",
                            onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
                            style: "cancel"
                          },
                          { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
                        ],
                        { cancelable: false }
                      );
                }
            }
    
    render(){
    return (
         <Autocomplete /> // first text input box
         <Autocomplete /> // second text input box
    )

}
```

Issue: the Alert box is not getting displayed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i think you are missing another condition when both fields are empty. is that the case?

Comment: My main purpose is to show the Alert box, which it is not showing right now, I can cover that case too.

Comment: is your onsubmit method being called correctly? maybe console.log on line one saying "hit" to ensure the behaviour is what you expect.

Comment: yes, this message is getting printed which is inside the if-condition, console.log("AlertBox: ");

Answer (score 0):

May be the `firstItem` and `secondItem` `value` is `empty` so it might not have entered inside.

Here is the snack you could verify with it.
[Link Here](https://snack.expo.io/Z2P02n68m)

Comment: as you can see in the code, there is a logging done inside the if-condition, that is getting printed so that means it is getting inside the if-condition, but I am not getting the Alert box.

Comment: And my logic is that if the first and second item are empty I want to show the Alert box.

Comment: could you update the snack so that i can look into it because in the snack I have a working demo for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am not able to see the Alert box in the above snack, when I check on the Web, but it is visible on Android, is it that Alert is not visible on Web, because I have been testing it on Web only.

Comment: ok I think it is an open issue : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6560
Got it working on WEB mode